# node.js async.series dont wait for query results

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, async.js

I´m trying to get results from a query to Splunk.

I have in search_normal.js this part of code, i export the function to be used in other file.

When this function is finished also export the results of this query.

```
exports.main = function(query, callback) {
    // This is just for testing - ignore it

    var username = "1111";
    var password = "2222";
    var scheme   = "https";
    var host     = "splunk.com";
    var port     = "8089";
    var version  = "default";

    var service = new splunkjs.Service({
        username: username,
        password: password,
        scheme: scheme,
        host: host,
        port: port,
        version: version
    });

    Async.chain([
            // First, we log in...
.
.
.
.
.
.
    exports.results;

....
```

In a second file called get_values.js, i tried to get this values and then send to a bot.

The problem is that when i tried to make the function async.series and wait for the results, it doesnt seem to work correctly and i dont know what i doing wrong.

The result that i have is **"1", "2" ,"Both are done"** then **"Done"**.

I wish to get **"Done", "1","2", "Both are done"**.

Do you Know if the async module or my usage have some issue? Thanks.

```
var myModule = require('./search_normal');

var async = require('async');

var call_splunk = myModule.main;



async.series
    ([  
        function (callback)
        {
            response=call_splunk(query_splunk, function() {
                console.log('Done')
            });
            console.log("1");

            await context.sendActivity(`Response is ${response}.`); // send result to bot

            callback();
        }
        ,
        function (callback)
        {
            console.log("2");

            callback();
        }
    ]
    ,
    function(err) 
    {
        console.log('Both are done');
        console.log(response);
    });
```

Comment: `await context`  This should be giving you an error, the function is not marked async.

Comment: Yes, that is correct but i still have the problem. i dont able to get  "Done", "1","2", "Both are done"

Comment: Assuming `call_splunk` is implemented correctly, you need to call the `callback()` from within the `call_splunk`  callback - do not just log `Done` in there

Comment: Hello Bergi, thanks for your help. Call_Splunk was copied  from Splunk SDK then i think it’s implemented correctly. Then i tried to add a callback in call_splunk, after console.log(“Done”) but it’s doesn’t work. I have the same problem.

Comment: Can you just try by moving these lines: ```console.log("1");```. ```await context.sendActivity(`Response is ${response}.`);```.  ```callback();``` inside ```call_splunk``` callback function (after ```console.log('Done')``` statement). And do not forget to add ```async``` keyword before callback function.

Comment: Hello Arjun, i added the callback(); inside of call_splunk but, now i have the error: Callback is not a function. ¿Could you explain what you suggest me?

Comment: Hello All, and thanks for your help now it’s working fine. Finally i just change in call_splunk the function for () and then it’s working.